# How to Get a Popup Window With Menu?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am opening a popup window from CRM 2011 for Outlook. The problem is I need the user to be able to print. If you do it from IE the browser print menu is available but from Outlook it is not. You just get a plain window. Hitting the Alt key does nothing when a popup opens from Outlook. None of the openStdWin() options seem to actually work from Outlook.

FYI I'm trying to print Dashboards (why MS left that out is beyond me). The solution we came up with is the following code hooked to a ribbon button. Then the user uses the built-in browser print functionality and the dashboard can be printed. But not from Outlook it seems. Any suggestions? (before anybody suggests it our client thinks print-screen is unacceptable)

```cs
function printCurrentDashboard() {    
    if (Xrm.Page.context.isOutlookClient()) {
        var pTarget = document.getElementById('dashboardFrame').src;
        openStdWin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + pTarget, 'test', 800, 600, 'menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,channelmode=no,directories=yes,fullscreen=no,location=yes,status=yes,titlebar=yes'); 
    }
    else {
        var pTarget = parent.document.getElementById('dashboardFrame').src;
        window.open(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + pTarget);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `openStdWinWithFeatures` vs `openStdWin`.

Comment: I may end up with that. However our client would like to be able to Print Preview which requires the menu.

Comment: Unfortunately when in Outlook it still does not actually use the features for some reason. It might be locked down for some security reason perhaps.